# Why use <g:textField /> in Grails?

Tags: grails, gsp, taglib

What is the reason to use g:textField in Grails if you're already familiar with standard HTML form tags?

If I understand correctly the following two markup alternatives are equivalent:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="${params.name}" id="name" />
<g:textField name="name" value="${params.name}" />
```

Are there any circumstances under which using g:textField would add value? Am I missing something?

Comment: I know this is old, but AFAIR, the 'value' in the textField g tag would be escaped, but I'm not sure the value in the standard input field would be in a GSP.  Maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The textField tag is provided as a convenience (slightly shorter than writing the HTML input) and is there to provide a full set of form tags.  Personally I prefer to write as much plain HTML as possible in my Grails views and only tend to use the tags that really offer a benefit such as the form tag.  I have not found an instance where using textField would have added any value outside of requiring a few less characters to type.

Comment: What benefit does the form tag provide?

Comment: @jamesmcmahon it's easier to link to specific controller actions where you want to send the submitted data.

Answer (score 2):

`<g:textField />` is not shorter as plain text field tag, except id attribute will be attached automatically.

However, I recommend you to use customized tags associating the bean values with input fields. That shortens the code a lot. For more information you can read http://www.jtict.com/blog/shorter-grails-textfield/
Also you can find useful stuff in Form Helper Plugin