# jQuery date picker set date is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery UI and trying to use datepicker. It works well but if I want to set current date to the field then it does not work. I have tried some but no luck. My attempts are below :

My input:

```
<g:textField id="admissionDate" class="form-control datepicker" name="admissionDate"
                                             required=""/>
```

Set date attempt on document ready:

```
$("#admissionDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
        }).datepicker("setDate",  "08/03/2016");
```

Also tried:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate",  "08/03/2016");
```

It highlight the current date if clicked but no set to text field.

Comment: what is `g:textField` ?

Comment: Replace textfield with input

Comment: @brk it's grails tag for html

Comment: @MurtazaHussain replaced but same result

Comment: `g:textField` is equivalent to `input` apparently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055574/why-use-gtextfield-in-grails. So it shouldn't be a problem. One question though. Why you're not using the standard tag? `input`

Comment: I mean to replace g: textfield to input

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your `g:textField` with input works.

```js
$("#admissionDate").datepicker();
$('#admissionDate').datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="admissionDate" class="form-control datepicker" name="admissionDate" style="width: 200px"/>
```

Comment: I am using jquery-1.11.1 and jquery-ui 1.12.1. Can it be the problem

Comment: or I need other essential file for it

Comment: As per the documentation - https://api.jqueryui.com/, `jQuery UI 1.12 supports jQuery 1.7 and newer` and you have less version. Use latest `jQuery Version`.

Comment: 1.7 was [released Nov 4, 2011](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases?after=1.7.2rc1) and 1.11.1 was [released May 2, 2014](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases?after=1.12.0). So 1.11.1 is newer than 1.7.

Comment: @Shinjo - yes, I misunderstood and that's why I deleted the comment.